# SAS: Get current year in YY format

Tags: date, sas, format

I want to assign the current year in a YY format to either a macro or data set variable.

I am able to use the automatic macro variables `&sysdate` or `&sysdate9` to get the current date.  However, extracting the year in a YY format is proving to be a nightmare.  Below are some examples of what I've been trying.

There exists the [YEARw.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/63324/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0jwqba6i1r0j1n1xe9ovnn0pamr.htm) format.  But when I try to use it I get errors or weird results.  For instance, running

```
data _null_;
  yy = year(input("&sysdate9.", year2.));
  put  yy=;
run;
```

produces the error

```
ERROR 48-59: The informat YEAR was not found or could not be loaded.
```

If I try to format the variable in the output, I get 1965 instead of the current year.  The following

```
data _null_;
  yy = year(input("&sysdate9.", date9.));
  put  yy= yy year2.;
run;
```

outputs

```
yy=2016 65
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works to get you the 2-digit year number of the current year:

```
DATA _NULL_;

YEAR = PUT(TODAY(),YEAR2.);
PUT YEAR;

RUN;
/* Returns: 16 */
```

To breakdown what I am doing here:

I use `TODAY()` to get the current date as a `DATE` type. `&SASDATE` needs to be converted to a `DATE`, but also it is the date that the SAS session started. `TODAY()` is the current date.

`PUT` allows us to pass in a non-character (numeric/date) value, which is why it is used with `TODAY()` as opposed to `INPUT`.

Comment: `PUT` is one distinction, for sure. Also, try replacing `TODAY()` with `SYSDATE` - you will see there is another distinction....

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 3):

I think it is worth exploring the issues here in more detail.

First, Formats are patterns for converting numeric values to a human readable format.  That's what you want to do here: convert a date value to a human readable format, in this case to a year.

Informats, on the other hand, convert human readable information to numeric values.  That's not what you're doing here; you have a value already.

Second, `put` matches with Formats, and `input` matches with informats, exclusively.

Third, you get close in your last try: but you misuse the `year` format.  Formats are basically value mappings, so they map every possible numeric value in their range (sometimes "all values" is the range, sometimes not) to a display value (string).  You need to know what kind of value is expected on the input.  `YEARw.` expects a date value as input, not a year value: meaning input is "number of days from 1/1/1960", mapped to "year".  So you cannot take a value you've already mapped to a year value and map it again with that method; it will not make any sense.

Let's look at it:

```
data _null_;
  yy = year(input("&sysdate9.", date9.));
  put  yy= yy year2.;
run;
```

`yy` contains the result of the `year` function - 2016.  Good so far.  Now, you need the 2 digit year (16); you can get that through `mod` function, if you like, or put/substr/input:

```
data _null_;
  yy = input(substr(put(year(input("&sysdate9.", date9.)),4.),3,2),2.);
  put yy=;
run;
```

`mod` is probably easier though since it's a number.  But of course you could've used `year`:

```
data _null_;
  yy = put(input("&sysdate9.", date9.),year2.);
  put yy=;
run;
```

Now, `yy` is character, so you could wrap that with `input(...,2.)` or leave it character depending on your purposes.

Finally - a use note on `&sysdate9.`.  You can easily make this a date without input:

```
"&sysdate9."d
```

So:

```
yy = put("&sysdate9."d,year2.);
```

That's called a date literal (and `"..."dt` and `"..."t` also work for datetime,time).  They require things in the standard SAS formats to work properly.

And as pointed out in Nicarus' answer, `today()` is a bit better than `&sysdate9` since it is guaranteed to be today.  If you're running this in batch or restart your session daily, this won't matter, but it will if you have a long-running session.

Answer (score 0):

- Apply the year function to the date variable
- Convert to string
- Take last 2 digits

EDIT: change input to PUT

```
    Year = substr(put(year(today()), 4.), 3);
```

Comment: That isn't working for me.  When I run `data _null_;
  Year = substr(input(year(today()), 4.), 3);
  put Year=;
run;`, I get a note about converting numeric to character and then Year=. is output.

Comment: I think `substr(input(` is always wrong.  `substr` is a text/character function and should never be applied directly to a numeric, which `input` generates in most cases.  Remove `in` and this should work as expected.